# parsing string from request data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to obtain a file's source code, and then parse a string from the source. The string I am trying to parse is `magic: 8susjdhdyrhsisj3864jsud` (not always the same string). If I observe the source by printing it out to the screen it shows just fine. When I parse the string sometimes I get a result, and other times I get nothing. Please see the following screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYWoZ.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJWvW.png. Now the string I want always appears in the source so it must be a regex issue? I've tried `findall` and `search`, but both methods give me the same outcome. Results sometimes and other times I get nothing. What seems to be my issue?

```
class Solvemedia():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key


    def timestamp(self, source):
        timestamp_regex = re.compile(ur'chalstamp:\s+(\d+),')

        print re.findall(timestamp_regex, source)


    def magic(self, source):
        magic_regex = re.compile(ur'magic:\s+\'(\w+)\',')

        print re.findall(magic_regex, source)


    def source(self):
        solvemedia = requests.Session()
        solvemedia.headers.update({
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
        })
        source = solvemedia.get('http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/challenge.script?k={}'.format(self.key)).text
        return source


    def test(self):
        js_source = self.source()

        print js_source
        self.magic(js_source)
        self.timestamp(js_source)


solvemedia = Solvemedia('HUaZ-6d2wtQT3-LkLVDPJB5C.E99j9ZK')
solvemedia.test()
```

Comment: You have *text* in those screenshots; please copy and paste that here rather than use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `.` in one of the values, but `\w` doesn't match dots. Compare:

```js
magic: 'AZJEXYx.ZsExcTHvjH9mwQ',
//             ^
```

with:

```
magic: 'xfF9i4YBAQP1EgoNhgEBAw',
```

A better bet is to allow all characters except a quote:

```
magic_regex = re.compile(ur"magic:\s+'([^']+)',")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> samples = [
...     u"magic: 'xfF9i4YBAQP1EgoNhgEBAw',",
...     u"magic: 'AZJEXYx.ZsExcTHvjH9mwQ',",
... ]
>>> magic_regex = re.compile(ur"magic:\s+'([^']+)',")
>>> for sample in samples:
...     print magic_regex.search(sample).group(1)
... 
xfF9i4YBAQP1EgoNhgEBAw
AZJEXYx.ZsExcTHvjH9mwQ
```

Comment: Ah! I completely missed that. Thanks for the help. It's working great now.